# Pronoun immediately following its antecedent

Tags: pronouns, word-order

Is placing a pronoun immediately after its antecedent in a sentence valid grammar?

Is there a term for this construction?

Some examples are:

- President Obama, he gave a speech last night.
- The speech, it was about the financial system.

I hear this on the Planet Money podcast at least once per episode.

Comment: It's not really grammatically valid. It's just a device commonly used in (primarily informal) speech, where that all-important noun is given added emphasis by being immediately re-referenced using a superfluous pronoun. You might hear it more on radio/tv/podcasts because it's a bit like saying, for example, *"President Obama! President Obama gave a speech last night." Mostly just a cheap trick to catch the listener's attention, IMHO.

Comment: @Fumble: Those comment-votes could be real votes, you know!

Comment: @drɱ65: Altruism to the fore! You have my permission to cut/paste/answer with my deathless prose. I'll even upvote you for it!

Comment: @Fumble: I can find no fault with it. It is a rhetorical trope, not at all objectionable.

Comment: @Robusto: It's certainly a rhetorical device, though I don't think I'd call it a [trope](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/trope). It's just repetition, for emphasis. Not that I object to it, but it isn't really grammatical. But it is very much a speech device, so it doesn't have to be. I think it's used to give the impression the hearer has just asked the question *"What interesting thing are you going to tell me about?"*. This device just allows you to baldly name your subject first to grab attention, *then* make a grammatical statement.

Comment: @Fumble: That John Updike, he sure knew how to write!

Comment: And yes, I misspoke about the trope. I had in mind to write "touch" and it came out the way it did. Stupid fingers.

Comment: @Robusto: Touche. But we *are* practiically in a forum here, and you can't deny that whatever we think about John Updike, he's certainly got us talking! Well, writing, I guess, but you know what I mean! :)

Comment: Thank you! This tic, it's been driving me crazy. It seems every podcaster, they all do it now.

Comment: "Frank, you left the door open!"

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Huddleston and Pullum (authors of ‘The Cambridge Grammar of the English Language’) call it ‘dislocation’, of which they distinguish two types, ‘left dislocation’, where the Noun Phrase is postioned to the left of the clause nucleus, and ‘right dislocation’, which describes the opposite. As an example of left dislocation, they give ‘One of my cousins, she has triplets.’ This construction seems to match exactly the OP’s examples.

Huddleston and Pullum further comment, ‘Dislocated constructions can be easier to understand than their basic counterpart.’

Answer (score 4):

This is *topic fronting* followed by a *resumptive pronoun*.

The pronoun does not always immediately follow its antecedent:

- President Obama, we heard him give a speech last night.

Whether it is valid grammar or not is an open question. It is not unusual to hear this type of construction in verbal communication. But it isn't often seen in writing. Then again, even when written, it's perfectly understandable.

Comment: There's a difference between topic-fronting and left-dislocation that you don't address.

Answer (score 0):

This is a pronominal appositive. Mark Twain uses them often in *The Adventures of Huckleberry Finn*. For example:

- *I reckon I got to light out for the Territory ahead of the rest, because Aunt Sally she's going to adopt me and sivilize me, and I can't stand it* (335).

There's an excellent article by Bruce Southard and Al Mulleron on Twain's idiosyncratic use of grammar, called “Blame it on Twain: Reading American dialects in *The Adventures of Huckleberry Finn*."

Comment: Not according to [Professor Liberman, at Language Log](https://languagelog.ldc.upenn.edu/nll/?p=629): 'the sentences at issue are not really appositives.... [Examples of various types of appositives] ... [our example] sentence ("My mother, she is a good person") is an example of a different construction where a non-vocative noun phrase in initial position is set off from a following sentence that contains one or more pronouns coreferential with the initial NP. Since Haj Ross's 1967 dissertation _Constraints on Variables in Syntax_, this construction has been known as "left dislocation" ....'

Answer (score -1):

When I was learning "proper" English grammar in the '50s, '60s and '70s, this so-called rhetorical device was taught to be a grammatical error, with the explanation that the pronoun was redundant.

Comment: Interesting! This might work better as a comment on one of the other posts, rather than an answer in and of itself.

Comment: Redundancy is not always unacceptable. Quite often, it fulfils a pragmatic role, it does.

Comment: It is a lie to say that the pronoun is redundant, because that pronoun marks the fact that the subject NP has been fronted. Without it, the entire sentence would be homonymous with a sentence that does not have a fronted NP.