# Validity of fronting important names in titles

Tags: grammar, grammaticality, punctuation, word-order

In Arabic, one can put for example **"Iraq, What is its destiny?"** as a title. **Is this structure valid in English? If it is, does it have a name? What about the punctuation? Generalizations and limitations?**

Comment: This looks like "left dislocation" (relevant question here: "[Pronoun immediately following its antecedent](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/42817)")

Comment: You will often see a colon used rather than a comma.

Comment: The duplicate asks about topic fronting followed by an  immediate anaphoric pronoun.  This is topic fronting followed by a delayed anaphoric pronoun (but still left-dislocation). But, although the example in the duplicate question sounds quaint and this doesn't, the questions are close enough to bracket.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This isn't something I've necessarily seen very often, and I don't know if it has a name. However, I believe it would be grammatically correct if you marked it with a colon, like so: "Iraq: What is its destiny?"